# Cross platform regex substring match for git

Tags: regex, bash, git, sed, grep

Sorry for yet another pattern matching question, but I'm struggling to to find a tool that will do a regex in a git hook. It needs to work on Windows, Mac and Linux.

This gnu grep works for Windows and Linux, but not Mac (because bsd)

```
echo "feature/EOPP-234-foo" | grep -Po -e '[A-Z]{4}-\d{1,5}'
```

This works for Mac and Linux, but not windows (because `<git>\usr\bin\egrep` don't seem to work)

```
echo "feature/EOPP-234-foo" | egrep -o '[A-Z]{4}-\d{1,5}'
```

`sed` might be the most common tool, but stuffed if I can get it to match:

```
echo "feature/EOPP-234-foo" | sed -n 's/^.*\([A-Z]{4}\-\d{1,5}\).*$/\1/p'
```

I've even tried `bash` matching with no luck

```
[[ "feature/EOPP-234-foo" =~ ([A-Z]{4}-\d{1,5}) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can also do a simple "if darwin, grep=egrep, else grep=grep, fi, $grep" kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to make POSIX tools run on Windows, you need to remember to use double quotation marks around your commands, not single quotes.

Also, you can use a common POSIX ERE compliant regex across all these environments. This means `\d` must be replaced with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` as `\d` is a PCRE only compliant construct.

You can use

```sh
grep -Eo "[A-Z]{4}-[0-9]{1,5}"
grep -Eo "[A-Z]{4}-[[:digit:]]{1,5}"
```